# Adding a file to a zip with truevfs throws exception

Tags: java, truevfs

I'm having an issue with adding a file into a zip with trueVFS. Here's a short code snippet:

```
package org.example.zipper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import net.java.truevfs.access.TFile;
import net.java.truevfs.access.TVFS;

public class Zipper {

    /**
     * @param args[0] path to file to be added to the zip
     * @param args[1] path to zip file
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Zipper().zip(args[0], args[1]);
    }

    public void zip(String filePath, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
        File source = new File(filePath);
        TFile.cp(source, new TFile(zipFilePath + File.separator + source.getName()));
        TVFS.umount();
    }
}
```

Results in the following exception (running with Java 11):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: No key manager available for class net.java.truecommons.key.spec.common.AesPbeParameters.
    at net.java.truecommons.key.spec.AbstractKeyManagerMap.manager(AbstractKeyManagerMap.java:36)
    at net.java.truevfs.comp.zipdriver.AbstractKeyController.keyManager(AbstractKeyController.java:153)
    at net.java.truevfs.comp.zipdriver.AbstractKeyController.sync(AbstractKeyController.java:149)
    at net.java.truevfs.kernel.spec.FsDelegatingController.sync(FsDelegatingController.java:122)
    at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.FalsePositiveArchiveController.sync(FalsePositiveArchiveController.java:236)
    at net.java.truevfs.kernel.spec.FsSync$1SyncVisitor.visit(FsSync.java:66)
    at net.java.truevfs.kernel.spec.FsSync$1SyncVisitor.visit(FsSync.java:59)
    at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.DefaultManager$3.call(DefaultManager.java:129)
    at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.DefaultManager.accept(DefaultManager.java:141)
    at net.java.truevfs.kernel.spec.FsSync.run(FsSync.java:77)
    at net.java.truevfs.access.TVFS.sync(TVFS.java:177)
    at net.java.truevfs.access.TVFS.umount(TVFS.java:56)
    at org.example.zipper.Zipper.zip(Zipper.java:22)
    at org.example.zipper.Zipper.main(Zipper.java:16)
```

Haven't been able to find the cause for this and would be grateful for a hint.